# SQL: comparisons and null values

Tags: sql, null, comparison, operators

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
SELECT 'HOPE', RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE, COUNT(DISTINCT RPRAWRD_PIDM) AS NumberOfStudents,  Sum(RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT) AS AmountPaid
FROM FAISMGR.RPRAWRD, FAISMGR.RFRBASE
WHERE RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = '1213'
     AND RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE = RFRBASE_FUND_CODE
     AND RPRAWRD_AWST_CODE = 'ACPT'
     AND RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT > 0 
     AND RFRBASE_FSRC_CODE = 'HOPE'
GROUP BY RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE;
```

The results yield 3952 records.

Some of the records contain NULL in RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT, and if I add

```
AND RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT IS NOT NULL
```

to the WHERE clause, I get exactly the same results: 3952 records. So, my question is: does >0 exclude null values because they evaluate as false, making IS NOT NULL unnecessary?

Comment: Yes - **no** row that has a `NULL` in `RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT` will be selected when you have `RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT > 0` already. So adding `IS NOT NULL` is indeed pointless and not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT > 0
```

will only return `true` if the value of `RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT` is greather than `0`. Comparing to `null` results in `unknown` and this is also `false`.

So yes, you don't need an extra `null` check.

Answer (score 0):

Most operations on `NULL` in SQL return `NULL`, which evaluates as false in conditionals.

```
mysql> SELECT NULL > 0;
+----------+
| NULL > 0 |
+----------+
|     NULL |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So yes, `RPRAWRD_PAID_AMT > 0` will filter out nulls, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.